# what is the meaning of more than one ELF program headers

Tags: elf

I have ELF file and it has more that 1 program header. If I understand correctly, the program header hold the executable part (the `_start`?). so what are the rest?

Answer (score -1):

There can be only one "program header table" in the elf file, which consists of an array of "Elf_Phdr" objects, each of which describes a segment in the program.  Sometimes people get confused and call each segment a "program header" (because of the Phdr name), but that's not really accurate.

Each segment in the program header describes a chunk of memory that needs to be allocated for the program and initialized somehow (generaly either zeroed, or initialized with data from the elf file), or some other data that is needed for dynamic linking.  It is possible to have an elf program with only one segment, but normally there are mulitple, to allow for different read/write/execute permissions.

Comment: Both Sun and Linux documentation https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html make reference to "program header table" and "program header", with the latter describing a single segment. I am not sure your use of "program header" to mean "program header table" is correct.

Comment: The man pages use the terms "program header" and "program header table" interchangeably for the whole table.  They use the terms "segment" or "Phdr" for element of the program header.